# Arch screen freezing / pausing

Tags: xorg, video, intel-graphics

My arch laptop has been freezing during video playback recently - not completely, but the video playback will freeze though audio will still play, and will unfreeze after input (moving the mouse or hitting a keyboard key). This also happens while playing games, as input from a gamepad doesn't cause the unfreezing.

However, this seems to only happen with some forms of video - it happens with VLC if the output is set to auto, but setting output to "X11 video output (XCB)" results in no freezing.

Freezing happens every few seconds, and seems to stick unless it receives input.

I'm guessing this is some sort of power saving feature with my laptop's hardware, which is a HP ZBook Studio g3. Currently running with the Nvidia card disabled through BIOS, so the graphics card is an Intel HD graphics 530.

Anything I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was with Compton - according to the Arch Wiki the only solution is to disable Compton when the issue arises.